# How to make multi regional and multi language in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, routes, frontend, nuxt.js

Currently, I'm trying to create a website with URL specification like this:

```
<domain>/:regional/:lang
```

However, if I use nuxt-i18n, the regional always start after the domain name

```
<domain>/:lang
```

There is a way to do something like this? or routing of regional should be handled by different tools or system (like load balancer)

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try? Any research?

Comment: please give more info, regional like continents? in there you can has multiple languajes? something like <domain>/asia/en, <domain>/europe/en, <domain>/america/en,  <domain>/asia/fr